# Using find before wc eliminates total

Tags: linux, unix, find

I'm using find to search through all subdirectories and current directory to find all .py files, and then run wc -l to find number of lines.  However, when I use find with wc, the Total field is left off, unlike when I run wc by itself.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
find . -name \*.py -exec wc -l {} \;
  187 ./check.py
   43 ./file.py
   33 ./mitch.py
       ...
 1014 ./serve.py
   41 ./test_scripts/line_graph.py
   39 ./welcome.py
```

But no total, but when I run `wc -l *.py` in a directory I get a total:

```
wc -l *.py
 187 check.py
  43 file.py
  94 log_com.py
 154 log_results.py
  33 mitch.py
1014 serve.py
  39 welcome.py
1564 total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wc` only outputs a *Total* value when it's called with more than one file as arguments.

From the [GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/wc-invocation.html):

> If more than one file is given, `wc` prints a final line containing the cumulative counts, with the file name `total`.

In your case, you cannot get a *Total* output, since you invoke `wc` once for each file found, so every subsequent `wc` call does not know about the previous one.

---

If you still want the total count, you can use the `globstar` option in Bash to recurse into directories and list `.py` files:

```
shopt -s globstar
wc -l **/*.py
```

Or, as grawity suggests, with GNU `find`'s `-exec command {} +` option, to have `find` substitute all found paths in `{}`, instead of calling each one individually (although there is a limit to the number of files it can substitute, just like with the glob approach).

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  So how would I go about doing this instead?

Comment: Updated my post. The most bullet-proof way would be to use `awk`– see grawity's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `total` field because there's only one file.

With the `-exec command {} ;` action, `find` runs *command* **once for every file**, with only a single argument added each time. So there is nothing that each `wc` invocation could calculate the total from.

You'd have to use `-exec command {} +` if you have GNU `find`; otherwise you'll need to pipe the list of files to `xargs command`.

(In this answer I'm not going to bother with the usual `-print0` suggestion, because if you don't have GNU find, you won't have `-print0` or even GNU xargs either. However, if your version of xargs *does* support `-d '\n'`, use that, because the default way xargs parses input isn't very safe.)

Note that this might still result in multiple `wc` invocations, because most operating systems (except maybe Hurd) have a limit on the maximum command-line length and/or maximum number of arguments to a single command, which a large number of files might exceed. @slhck's suggestion of using `**/*.py` would also hit the same limit (early Unixes having had very low limits is why `xargs` was created in the first place).

Another alternative is to use `awk` for the final calculation:

```
find ... | awk '$2 != "total" {sum += $1; print}
                END {printf "%7d total\n", sum}'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you hit the limit in practice already? (Of course I think it should be mentioned regardless.)

Comment: @slhck: Once – when trying to remove everything from pacman's downloaded package cache. (I had mistakenly used an absolute path in the command, so that doubled the length of every path.) I've gotten used to `find -delete` as an alternative to `rm -rf *` since then.